# Was Lou always Jacob's dad?

Tags: plot-explanation, hot-tub-time-machine

In [*Hot Tub Time Machine* (2010)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1231587), there is a scene where Lou is interrupted having sex with Kelly, Jacob's mother (it has already been established that Jacob was conceived that weekend and that his mom is kind of a slut, leaving a paternal question in the air). When he is interrupted, Jacob disappears from existence, thus revealing that Lou is Jacob's father and he must finish in order for Jacob to still exist.

**My question is was Lou always Jacob's father?** I don't remember them ever mentioning him having sex with Kelly as one of the things that he has to do to avoid changing the future, and that seems like it would be something you would remember.

Comment: Literal (grand)Father paradox.

Comment: Also they completely change the future. Or jumped back into an alternative present, ala BTTF.